# Function to return values after confirming date is in date-range

Tags: arrays, excel, date, excel-2010, date-range

I've been struggling with what I thought should be a fairly straightforward function:

- Looking at a group of records and the payment date;
- comparing the date to a date range (does date fall in July, 2011, etc.);
- for all true, sum the payment values.

I have researched this here and elsewhere, found similar answers, but nothing fits the scenario. I'm not sure if I should make this an array function or if other, more recent functions, will get the job done. My last attempt was using `SUMIFS()` where A:A is the invoice date, B:B is the payment value, H:H is the beginning of the month, and I:I is the end of the month:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$113,$A$2:$A$113,A2,$A$2:$A$113,">="&H2,$A$2:$A$113,"<="&I2)
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Someday I'll try to calculate the date range on the fly, instead of having the "start/end" date columns.

Comment: Thanks for the additional input... and any future queries will be formatted like your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `=SUMIFS(B2:B113,A2:A113,">="&H2,A2:A113,"<="&I2)` was suitable.